# Update Multiple Objects using SQL way in Django

Tags: django

I have a `Comment` model that needs the admin approval. I am providing a view for the admin to do that.

However, I am using an expensive way to update the approval status.

```
comments = # a list that contain Comment objects

for c in comments:
    c.approved = True
    c.approved_on = #now
    c.save()
```

As you can see I am looping over all the objects in the list and every time I am hitting the database.

I am looking for a way that makes me do something similar to this in SQL

```
UPDATE comments SET approved = 1 WHERE id IN(...........)
```

This will do the same thing in one SQL query.

Is there any way to do this in Django?

like this with using an approve method in the manager?

```
Comment.objects.filter(pk__in=[1,2,3]).approve().save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way:

```
def approve(self):
    return self.get_queryset().update(approved=True)
```

**NOTE**: this solution has problem. `post_save` and `pre_save` signals will not be called.

If you need this signals, you must iterate items like you do in your example.

```
def approve(self):
    qs = self.get_queryset()
    for c in qs:  # hit database!
        c.approved = True
        c.approved_on = #now
        c.save()
    return qs
```